# How can I make column names from column content?

Tags: r, dataframe

I've looked around quite a bit but can't manage to solve my problem. I downloaded data from ICE in the following format:

```
Bond  Date        Return
A     1997-03-31  0.899
B     1997-03-31  1.223
C     1997-03-31  1.543
D     1997-03-31  0.003
A     1997-06-30  0.724
B     1997-06-30  1.650
C     1997-06-30  1.435
D     1997-06-30  0.050
```

However, I'd like to join it as follows:

```
Date        A     B     C     D
1997-03-31  0.899 1.223 1.543 0.003
1997-06-30  0.724 1.650 1.435 0.050
```

Any suggestions on how I could do this would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you probably want to look at `tidyr::pivot_wider()`

Comment: Thanks a lot! @Chris